# Область видимости методов (сообщений)

Tags: objective-c

Написано, что для филдов можно выставлять визибилити в h-файле просто: @private, @protected. А как быть с методами (сообщениями)? Ведь для них нельзя задать область видимости также, как для филдов, но ведь иначе все приватные методы будут торчать наружу, что не очень хорошо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так объявите эти методы в m-файле перед реализацией. Они будут не видны тому, кто сделает импорт h-файла.

```
#import "...

@interface Test ()

- (BOOL) isTest123: (NSString*) param;

@end

@implementation Test

@synthesize ...

 - (id) init ...

 - (BOOL) isTest123: (NSString*) param {
    return NO;   // этот метод не виден при импорте
 }

@end
```

Comment: Мне кажется, он будет вызываться в любом случае. Это же сообщение, а не метод. Просто xCode будет подчеркивать его как warning.

Comment: Ага, это стандартный способ определения "приватных методов" классов. То есть мы создаем безымянную категорию класса: Test(), в которой перечисляем приватные методы. Да, компилятор будет выдавать варнинг, если вы попытаетесь достучаться к приватному методу извне, но это особенность разработки: к варнингам нужно относиться очень внимательно. А если в безымянной категории описать свойство, то компилятор будет уже выдавать ошибку при попытке доступа к свойству снаружи.